# How to get results of multiple join

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following setup:

```
...
Survey.hasMany(Question, {as: 'Questions'});
Question.hasMany(Answer, {as: 'Answers'});
```

How do I get the complete record set for a single Survey? I know how to get all the questions for a survey, but I want each question to also have all the answers associated with it.

```
Question.findAll({
  where: {
    surveyId: req.surveyId
  }
}).then(function (questions) {
  // Now how do I join questions with their answers?
}, function (err) {

});
```

My ideal structure is:

```
var survey = [
  {
    question: 'some question',
    answers: [{...},{...},...]
  }, 
  {
    ...
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the associated model.

```
Question.findAll({
    where: {
        surveyId: req.surveyId
    },
    include: [{
        model: Answer,
        as: 'Answers'
    }]
}).then(function (questions) {
    console.log(questions[0].Answers);
}, function (err) {

});
```

Or you can query on the `Survey` model and include both `Question` and `Answer`:

```
Survery.findAll({
    where: {
        id: req.surveyId
    },
    include: {
        model: Question,
        include: {
            model: Answer
        }
    }
}).then(function (surveys) {
    console.log(surveys[0]);
}, function (err) {

});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know where in the documentation this is shown? I'd love to see what else I don't know about.

Comment: You can check these: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/ http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/

Comment: Thanks! If you have any time, I've got another Sequelize.js question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941290/how-to-filter-based-on-an-include-in-sequelize-js) that is partially based on what I learned from your answer above